# Can I use AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) components/tags on a page that is not a valid AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

Can I use AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) components/tags on a page that is not a valid AMP page?

Will I have advantages or disadvantages with this? Is it a good practice or not?

I would like to use the AMP components/tags by the way it load the elements (like amp-carousel and amp-img), but I can not fully convert my website to AMP since I have custom javascript codes that AMP page dont allow that I use (that do not apply using amp-iframe).

Is it better for me to keep standard elements and other libraries, or is it valid for me to use AMP components even though the page is not a valid AMP page?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do that. Bloat is bloat no matter what tags you wrap around it. Keep your pages lite and your code clean and you won't have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major advantage of `AMP` is making the loading time better. You can achieve that by getting rid of Javascript, replacing `img` with `amp-img` etc.
`AMP` offers plenty of it's own JS implementations for example for Twitter, Google Analytics, Pinterest and so on. See here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components

Here you can find the information, that custom Javascript is restricted: 
https://www.ampproject.org/how-it-works/

If you don't want to resign from custom dynamic content, you can have two versions of you page and link them in `<head>`.

**Disadvantages of having not fully AMP conform page?** I think that Google might not index AMP pages that are not fully valid with AMP validation rules.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is going to work as one of the design principle of AMP is to [Keep all third-party JavaScript out of the critical path](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/how-amp-works/), meaning no author-written Javascripts except those specified by AMP Pages. So it's either you have an AMP version of your website or a non-AMP (canonical) version.