# What if I have AMP pages that are not AMP compliant

Tags: jquery, amp-html, owl-carousel

We are well into developing a new website using AMP, and are finding that some of our requirements are incompatible with AMP.  For example the AMP carousel does not behave well when you try to display more than one slide at a time, so the designer is pointing out pages that do what she wants by using the Owl carousel, which in turn uses jQuery.

We don't want to take the time to rewrite all our pages to work without AMP, so is it bad to use jQuery on some of our pages that declare that they use AMP, but are not actually AMP compliant?  Will Google penalize us for this?

I see different opinions.  @Dan at [Using amp script in non-amp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939367/using-amp-script-in-non-amp-page) seems to think it's probably OK, but @pidabrow at [Can I use AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) components/tags on a page that is not a valid AMP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270227/can-i-use-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages-components-tags-on-a-page-that-is-not-a) thinks the opposite.

Comment: You can try amp-carousel if haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery in your AMP, AMP-validator will throw an error saying the AMP is invalid.

You can still publish your pages, however, they won't get any benefit in Google search results and will be treated as normal non-AMP.

Comment: That is very helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to answer this!